# Vintage Peugeot pulls towards left when riding

Tags: maintenance, handlebars

I've bought a second hand old Peugeot, I really enjoy the bike, but I'm having a balance problem with it, pulls to the left when riding.

Could it be related with the handlebars? They are crooked.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles! This site is a Question and Answer site, not a traditional forum. "Ramblings" tend to get removed. It would be best to ask each question separately, and include the essential question in the title, instead of putting multiple related questions in a single post.

Comment: And add the photos to the post, rather than use links, please.

Comment: Do you mean that the bike pulls to the left when you're riding?

Comment: Can't tell anything from the photos posted. How about a shot from the front? May be a bent fork, crooked bars, wheel out of dish, frame problem... lots of things are possible

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks for the fast replies, changes and advices on my post. Yes, WTHarper, if I remove my hands of the handlebar it goes towards to the left. The handlebar is crooked so, I have a strong feeling that might that. I will put some more photos today later on. Thanks

Comment: @antao could you please edit this information about the crooked handlebar right into the question itself as it might be a crucial information to answering your question?

Comment: The (sorta) worst case scenario is a bent frame.  If the headset is not in the same plane as the rear triangle then you'll get a tendency to pull to one side.  It's only "sorta" worst case, though, since an old steel frame can be straightened by someone who knows what they're doing.

Comment: Did you look over the bike and find a serial number?

Comment: I would have that bike checked out at a shop. It really looks like it has been through at least one serious crash. Frame might be fine, but I would replace the stem/handlebars if you find any scratches/damage.

Comment: Going to check for the serial number and will still post some more photos today. The previous owner told me exactly that, that crashed with the bike, he had the front wheel replaced. I really like the bike, it was cheap (60e) and probably the best solution it's really take it to a shop, have it checked and replace the handlebars.

Comment: Added some more photos, sorry for the bad quality... my phone is a bit crappy.

Comment: I'm guessing you're going to have to replace more than the handlebars.

Comment: The bike doesn't look that old, maybe mid-late 80s, and appears to have been kept out of the weather, so it should be pretty good if the major components are sound.  It's hard to tell -- the fork may be slightly bent, the result of the classical running into a parked car accident.  Not a real expensive bike, but considerably better than your discount store unit.

Comment: The rear brake cable housing probably should be replaced.

Comment: It has been in a frontal crash and the fork tines are bend back subtly.  One will be more bent than the other.  I bet it feels very sketchy if you hit a small bump in the road, trying to crab sideways.  I'd also bet that riding straight forward, the back wheel rides to the side of the front wheel.  You can ride through a puddle on otherwise dry concrete to confirm that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a vintage peugeot and one characteristic of older steel frames like them is horizontal dropouts. Although they have their advantages it also means you must be careful to align the rear wheel properly when putting it back on the bike.

If you look carefully from above the wheel should be exactly central between the chainstays and the seatstays. Although hard to see, in your 2nd photo it looks as though it's off to the left a bit. Just loosen the QR and carefully adjust the axle's position in each dropout until you have the wheel central.

This is most likely the cause of your problem.

[image]

Comment: Looking at the other pics, they sure don't look like horizontal drop-outs.

Comment: It is hard to see but I think they are. Maybe OP can provide a more detailed photo. In the [link provided by @batman](http://marksbikes.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/bike-mysteries/) there is a close-up of the dropouts which are clearly horizontal so if the model is the same I think we can be sure they are. In any case I have yet to see a vintage peugeot without horizontal dropouts.

Answer (score 4):

Straighten your seat. It's pointed a bit to the right, causing your body to slightly slant to the left to compensate, moving center of the mass a bit to the left, causing whole bike to lean and turn left.

Comment: Yes, that's also true. Thanks Mladen. I would vote up on your anwser, but I still can't.

Comment: Np, also, check that wheels are reasonably true and centered within forks (having the same distance from both fork arms).

Answer (score 2):

http://marksbikes.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/bike-mysteries/ might be a useful link to start with - It says Anjou on it, so its reasonable to guess its a Peugeot Anjou of some year. In that link, they do link to some old Peugeot catalogues and what not (for example: http://i419.photobucket.com/albums/pp271/qeugeot/1989fr/1989fr_27.jpg is a 1989 Peugeot Anjou). Depending on what parts of the bike are original,  you may be able to figure out what year it is from the catalogues.