# Information on Peugeot Anjou model?

Tags: vintage, touring-bikes

I am about to buy a second hand Peugeot Anjou bicycle (probably a 89 model) I found on Wallapop but I cannot seem to find any information on the internet on it.

Any help?

Mainly what I am looking for is the:

- Wheel size
- Frame type (steel?)

I am asking before I go and see it as I want to value its price (guy says 200 euros).

Any info on this bicycle is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a nice pic, see http://www.re-cycle.com/images/Peugeot/1989_French/1989_27.jpg

For the specs see http://www.re-cycle.com/images/Peugeot/1989_French/1989_28.jpg

Unless you read French, you'll need to translate the terms.

(I see it says the tires are 700c, and on my reading it doesn't mention frame material).

Comment: yeah... i guess i'll find out... what do you think of its price?

Comment: It all depends on what it's worth to you, versus how you value 200 Euros. From the Web searches I did to find the answer, I got the impression that some people think it's collectable. So that all means "No idea". But we can be sure the frame is steel.

Answer (score 1):

So you're asking "what do I look for when inspecting a vintage bike with intent to purchase" ?

Firstly are you after a machine to ride?  Or something old to collect and store?  Because the requirements are totally different

Your questions:
The wheel size will be 27" in steel from new, or it could have been swapped out with 27" alloy or 700c alloy or steel.  Read the sidewall of the tyre/tire to know.  622 means its a 700c, and 27" means pretty much that.  It could also have 28".

Frame - take a small magnet with you  Even a fridge magnet will tell you if a part is ferrous and therefore steel.  The frame is most likely steel.

If you're buying for a collection, you want original everything.  Papers, receipts, booklets, anything it came with.  Original running gear in poor condition is more collectable than incorrect running gear

On the other hand if you want a bike to ride, 200 euros seems a lot for an old bike.  It has to fit your body size and shape, and then everything else comes afterwards, like looking for corrosion, pitting in bearing races etc.

Some Peugot specific info on this page:   [Vintage Peugeot tends towards the left when riding](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/18637/vintage-peugeot-tends-towards-the-left-when-riding)

And this one should be a leader https://marksbikes.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/bike-mysteries/

Comment: It is for riding yes.

Comment: I had seen those links but none has some specification info on them. Thanks for the answer though!